# How to do an upsert on computed columns

Tags: postgresql

I have an insert SQL statement and I would like to update the qty when there is a conflict. The unique index is based on user_id, symbol, ex_date, settle_date.

Scenario:

Before the dividend ex_date, the user purchased more shares so instead of inserting a new record, I like to update the qty and the computed columns.  Can ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE the best solution?  What would be the correct ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE statement?

```
insert into cash_dividend_details ( 

user_id ,
lastname ,
firstname ,
middlename ,
symbol ,
qty ,
gross_cash_dividend ,
cash_dividend_tax ,
net_cash_dividend ,
dividend_entitled_date ,
ex_date ,
payable_date 

)

(

SELECT s.user_id, 
        v.lastname,
        v.firstname,
        v.middlename,
        s.symbol, 
        s.qty , 
        (s.qty*d.cash_div_rate)::numeric(20,2),
        ((s.qty*d.cash_div_rate)*.10)::numeric(20,2) ,
        (s.qty*d.cash_div_rate)-((s.qty*d.cash_div_rate)*.10)::numeric(20,2) , 
        date(d.ex_date - interval '1 DAY') ,
        date(d.ex_date) , 
        date(d.settle_date) 
FROM stock_portfolio_summary s 
INNER join vw_qbe_vendorslist v on ( v.listid = s.user_id )
INNER join dividend d on ( d.symbol = s.symbol )
WHERE date(s.added_date) <= date(d.ex_date - interval '1 DAY')
  AND s.qty > 0
  AND is_cash_dividend_processed is FALSE
ORDER by d.settle_date asc, user_id 

) ON CONFLICT ( s.user_id, s.symbol, d.ex_date, d.settle_date ) DO
        UPDATE SET ( s.qty .....
--ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING ;
```

Here's a sample data:
[image]

If user buys more shares tomorrow and before ex_date and payable_date, for example, 1000sh FB then

[image]

Comment: Why use `ON CONFLICT`? Just  `UPDATE cash_dividend_details SET qty = qty + <new_qty> WHERE user_id = <id> AND  symbol = <symbol>, ...`,

Comment: @AdrianKlaver ,  the daily process is to insert data to the same table after the exchange is closed.  So we don't want to append new records to existing records but instead update the qty based on user_id, ex_date, payable_date, symbol.

Comment: You are going to have to show some example data as I don't see how "... update the qty based on user_id, ex_date, payable_date, symbol" differs from what I suggested? Also  I don't see how "... don't want to append new records to existing records" fits in with "...update the qty...".

Comment: 1) Put that information in the question not a comment 2) The data does actually show what you are trying to achieve. In other words what is needed is I start with this I have this new data and I want to end up with this.

Comment: What version of Postgres?

Comment: Postgres 12 , will plan to upgrade to 14 on July.